# Angular 5 and .NET Core 2.1 API: Getting current time in user's timezone

Tags: c#, angular, datetime, asp.net-core-2.1

This works but I was wondering if anyone has a better method.

**Goal:**

Get client's DateTime offset and return DateTime values in client's local time.

**What I did:**

On the front-end, I created a custom header and passed it in the request.

```
export class ItemService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'TimeZone-Offset': `${new Date().getTimezoneOffset()}`
    })
  }

  constructur(private authHttp: HttpClient) { }

  getItems() {
    return this.authHttp.get<Item[]>(this.baseUrl + 'items', 
      { headers: this.httpOptions.headers });
  }
}
```

Then on the back-end, I pulled in the header value, converted it to an integer, then converted UTC time to local using the `AddMinutes` functionality.

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetItems()
  {
    var currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(int.Parse(
      Request.Headers["TimeZone-Offset"] != StringValues.Empty
        ? Request.Headers["TimeZone-Offset"][0] : "0"));

    // ...logic to return items
  }
```

So, if the TimeZone-Offset header is added, the server will be able to convert DateTimes to the client's local time, otherwise, the DateTimes will be given in UTC. Is there a better way? Should I just leave everything UTC on the server, and then do a UTC to Local conversion on the client-side?

Comment: Hi, JED. I think it is better to save datetime in UTC on server side. And then convert to local on client-side (you may use moment.js). In all my projects I use such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make shure that you send every Timestamp as UTC to the client. Something like "2018-12-12T20:13:00.000Z". If you convert that to a JavaScript Date it should display automatically in the local time zone of the Browser.

Comment: That's what I've been debating... and that's what my app actually does. However, I'm fond of the idea of being able to send back DateTimes in the client's local time because some API calling services like Postman don't have the functionality to make the conversions for you. Obviously if the end-user is creating their own interface for the API, then they should be able to make the conversions themselves. It's just something I've been mulling over.

Comment: However, being that I specifically asked this question about Angular, you're probably correct!

Answer (score 1):

You can install [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) via NuGet.
 
Then, if you manage to pass in your header a timezone information like `Europe/Berlin`, you could do the following in your backend:

```
using TimeZoneConverter;
...
string timezoneString = "Europe/Berlin";
TimeZoneInfo timezone = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo(timezoneString);
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, timezone));
```

Comment: I think you're mixing IANA time zones and Windows time zones here. TimeZoneInfo works with the timeZoneId from Windows. Something Like "W. Europe Standard Time". And "Europe/Berlin" is a IANA time zone.

Comment: @keuleJ Thanks! You're right - happened to work for me because of my OS. Edited to use TimeZoneConverter.